# REST Api implementation in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, parameters, google-cloud-functions

I am currently implementing Rest API standards in firebase functions. I am searching for an option for passing `id` as params. But I am not sure where my current Implementation was sufficient to change like that.

My code looks like this.

```
export const user = functions.https.onRequest(userModule);
```

and the URL will be like

```
https://firebaseapp<baseurl>/user
```

I need to pass the user id in the URL(not as query param)

expected URL

```
https://firebaseapp<baseurl>/user/{userId}
```

Is there any way to make the URL look like the above in firebase functions?

Comment: Can you share what `userModule` is? If that's an instance of Express app then you can follow my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object from [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to access the path parameters using `params` property as shown below:

```
app.get("/user/:userId", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Path params", req.params); // { userId: "USER_ID" }
  res.json(req.params);
}));
```